# Django how to add foreignkey - multiple choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello i created two models and second must use this first, for example first model is product and second is shop which contains few products.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=40)
    price = models.FloatField("price")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Shop(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null = True)
    name = models.CharField("shopname", max_length=40)
    salary = models.FloatField("salary")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is it good start? I want create something which will give me possibility to add many Product.models to Shop.model. How to create it?

And second problem is - now when i click

> python manage.py migrate homebudget

i have information

```
   (venv) C:\Users\noname\nowe\budget>python manage.py makemigrations homebudget
Migrations for 'homebudget':
  0011_auto_20150513_1817.py:
    - Alter field price on product
    - Alter field name on product
    - Alter field name on shop
    - Alter field salary on shop

(venv) C:\Users\noname\nowe\budget>python manage.py migrate homebudget
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: homebudget
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying homebudget.0002_shop_product...Traceback (most recent call las
t):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init_
_.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init_
_.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py
", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py
", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\command
s\migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.
py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=f
ake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.
py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration
.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, projec
t_state)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operation
s\fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\sch
ema.py", line 176, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\sch
ema.py", line 74, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema
.py", line 194, in effective_default
    default = field.get_default()
  File "C:\Users\noname\nowe\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\relate
d.py", line 1930, in get_default
    if isinstance(field_default, self.rel.to):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and typ
es

(venv) C:\Users\noname\nowe\budget>
```

Comment: I think you are getting that error because you are passing a string as the first argument to your model fields. The field calls don't need that.

Comment: @nofinator no, that's just the optional verbose name, it's unnecessary but fine. znawca please post the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i edited first post

Answer (score 0):

Running this code doesn't give me any errors, but it looks like nofinator has a point that the field calls don't expect names as positional arguments. If you want them it would probably be better to use `verbose_name` e.g.,

```
salary = models.FloatField(verbose_name="salary")
```

But it doesn't make a lot of sense until you use it to give a more human readable name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need quotes around `'Product'` when defining the foreign key:

```
product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null = True)
```

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been
>   defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model
>   object itself:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: The quotes are unnecessary if the class is defined before the class calling it. So in this case, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a `models.ManyToManyField` not a Foreign Key. The way you have it written now is a `Product` can have many `Shop`s.

At the very least you'd want the `Shop` to have many `Product`s; in that case to have a `ForeginKey` in `Product` in that case.

You need to write `verbose_name="salary"`, etc. to get rid of the problem.